# Retrieving intermediate values for raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, raw-input

If I have a thread running in the background, is there any way it can retrieve from Python's raw_input what has been typed so far? Example: User is sitting at prompt and typing away. I would like to receive what has been typed so far at the 5 second mark, 10 second mark, etc.

Relatedly, is there any type of KeyboardEvent indicating that typing is going on?

Additionally, is there any way to modify raw_input's buffer? Clear the buffer from a different thread?

For threading I'm using the 'signal' module.

Comment: Your question is very broad, you've not provided any code or explained what you're doing, for instance what package are you using for your "threads"?

Comment: You'll need to poll stdin directly, `raw_input()` cannot do what you want.